# Loop through dropdown webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How would I loop through 9 selections in drop down list ... say for instance it has 9 different values how would I make it go through all of them using select?

Ex. Values were
Red
Blue
Green
Purple

So far I have

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++){

        WebElement ClubDropDown = driver.findElement(By.id("tenantList"));

        Select CDropdown = new Select(ClubDropDown);

// This is the part I'm stuck on how to make it loop through the drop downs and preform the defined public void cases


         OpenMp(); // This is one of my public void test cases
    }
```

Comment: Can you consider sharing the relevant HTML DOM please? Do mention your manual testing steps so we can guide you better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in Java8

```
Select cDropdown = new Select(ClubDropDown);
cDropdown.getOptions().forEach(el -> {
                //do something
});
```

P.S. start variable names from lower case letter  `ClubDropDown -> clubDropDown`